# Как получить путь к папке данных программы из сервиса?

Tags: java, android, service

Создаю и запускаю сервис:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service
{
  private static String m_PathToExternalStorageDirectory;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() 
  {
    BackgroundService.m_PathToExternalStorageDirectory = 
        getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

При активации приложения это работает, но проблема в том, что через какое-то время Android перезапускает сервис и (без Activity?) возвращается пустая строка. Вместо getBaseContext() ставил this, getContext(), getApplicationContext() - все едино. Как-то можно этот путь получить другим способом?

UPD: Прошу прощения, разобрался сам - в этом коде все в порядке, проблема была в другом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Путь к папке с приложением – [`getApplicationInfo().dataDir;`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir)